# Placing one vocabularly underneath another?

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

I've got the following two vocabularies:

Categories, with items:

- Big
- Medium
- Small

Make, with items:

- Samsung
- Whirlpool
- KIC

I've then made a product content type, where these two categories are required.

My problem comes in where I want a menu (preferably using taxonomy menu and dhtml menu) so I can obtain the following menu:

- Big

  - Samsung
  - Whirlpool
  - KIC
- Medium

  - Samsung
  - Whirlpool
  - KIC
- Small

  - Samsung
  - Whirlpool
  - KIC

How can I go about accomplishing this?

I know, normally it would be fairly easy if I made only ONE vocabularly, and for each taxonomy term, i add the make as sub-terms... but I want to do it my way, so that if a new make comes on, that I don't have to go add it to each category. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) is the best tool like that I've heard of, but it doesn't play well with two different vocabularies- the module needs the tiered relationships to be defined externally, either by a taxonomy hierarchy, Views, and so on.

I don't think the model of two separate vocabularies will easily be supported by any existing module. If one of the "categories" were presented as a series of nodes tagged by the first category, you might build something with Views & Hierarchical Select to achieve what you want.

Comment: It doesnt quite do what I want, but it's the next best thing. :-)